# WiX not rendering images correctly

Tags: bitmap, wix, wix3.5

I'm trying to write a custom WiX dialog which, as part of its workflow, shows an error image in response to certain conditions. However, WiX appears to be ignoring my dimensions and displaying as it feels fit. Here's my code:

```
<Binary Id="WixUI_FailureImg" SourceFile="$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)..\Resources\Failure.ico" />
<Control Id="TestResult_Failure" Type="Icon" IconSize="16" X="15" Y="206" Width="16" Height="16" Text="WixUI_FailureImg">
    <Condition Action="hide">LOGON_VALID = "1"</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show">LOGON_VALID = "0"</Condition>
</Control>
```

I've included a snippet of the resulting dialog below, with the original image (a 16x16 .ico) in the background. As you can see, the image has been scaled upwards, and there is no transparency around the image. I've tried 8-bit and 24-bit bitmaps as well icons, but they all produce the same result. Is there something that I am doing obviously wrong?

[image: example of borked image]

**UPDATE:**

In case you were wondering how the dynamic images works, here's the relevant section:

```
<Control Id="TestResult_Success" Type="Icon" IconSize="16" X="15" Y="210" Width="12" Height="12" Text="WixUI_SuccessImg">
    <Condition Action="hide">LOGON_VALID = "0"</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show">LOGON_VALID = "1"</Condition>
</Control>
<Control Id="TestPrompt_Success" Type="Text" X="35" Y="210" Width="322" Height="10" Text="!(loc.SqlSelectDlgConnectionValid)">
    <Condition Action="hide">LOGON_VALID = "0"</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show">LOGON_VALID = "1"</Condition>
</Control>
<Control Id="TestResult_Failure" Type="Icon" IconSize="16" X="15" Y="210" Width="12" Height="12" Text="WixUI_FailureImg">
    <Condition Action="hide">LOGON_VALID = "1"</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show">LOGON_VALID = "0"</Condition>
</Control>
<Control Id="TestPrompt_Failure" Type="Text" X="35" Y="210" Width="322" Height="10" Text="!(loc.SqlSelectDlgConnectionInvalid)">
    <Condition Action="hide">LOGON_VALID = "1"</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show">LOGON_VALID = "0"</Condition>
</Control>
```

As you can guess from the screenshot, the page is related to establishing a SQL connection; I have a custom action that creates a connection string based on the user's input, and attempts to validate it. If it's valid (`LOGON_VALID = "1"`), I get a tick image and some text to say everything is good, otherwise I get a warning icon and some text to warn the user. Of course, the Next button is also controlled by this value.

Comment: asking a separate question..curious to know..are you changing image dynamically? i mean the image will appear as per the condition?

Comment: Yes; so there is a TestResult_Success control which shows a green tick if LOGON_VALID = 1, and hides it if LOGON_VALID = 0. The images are the same size and at the same location.

Comment: can you please share some code for dynamically updating the image?

Comment: I've updated the original question to show my solution. Not clever, but it works :-)

Comment: thanks a lot...i tried this a lot but never got..i was missing `'Text="WixUI_FailureImg"'` which i got from your code. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

X, Y, Width, and Height are in "installer units," not pixels. Converting installer units to pixels depends on the visual theme, font size, and DPI settings. Your best bet is to make it look good on default settings.

Comment: It's a shame the WiX documentation doesn't make this clear. In the end, I resorted to just trying a range of values, and found that for my 16x16 image, setting the Width and Height to 12, and leaving IconSize at 16, produced the intended results (at the default visual theme/font size/DPI settings, as you note).

Comment: @DavidKeaveny I've also had to scale up my image by 1.3333333 times what I set in my WiX UI. This was such a ridiculous step (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997742/how-do-you-optimize-a-jpeg-image-for-msi-installers/29012944#29012944) Thank you so much for posting back what has worked for you, David. Its helped me out tremendously.