# How do you optimize a JPEG image for MSI installers?

Tags: graphics, wix, windows-installer, installation, rendering

I am dealing with a splash screen logo and I've noticed that on different OS versions this image gets distorted, but it happens to work when dealing with Windows 8.1, but not on Windows 7 or Vista. I've been using Adobe Fireworks in conjunction with Illustrator to generate it, and I must have tried a ton of different settings but I can't get the same experience across all operating systems.

I load it into my WiX project as follows:

```
<Binary Id="SplashBinary" SourceFile="Splash.jpg"/>
```

And I use it like so:

```
<Control Id="SplashBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="373" Height="252" Text="SplashBinary" TabSkip="yes" Sunken="no" Disabled="yes" />
```

I've tried using the width and height above but it would not look good on 8.1 (too blurry), so I doubled it on the image to get a crisper result in Windows 8.1 (its perfect in 8.1). But again, it looks like its aliasing is messed up on 7 and Vista. Can anyone shed some light as to what I need to do to get a consistent experience? What do I need to do to my image to export it such that it renders a nice crisp result on these platforms?

Comment: I had some problems once with an image received from a client, but all I did was to open it with Photoshop and save it back. Don't know what was the problem. Also you should check the DPI settings on those machines, to make sure that is the same for all.

Comment: All the DPI settings across my machines are set to Smaller, and resolutions are all 1920 x 1080, which makes this so bizarre.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache When you used it in a control, do you know the width and height of the control you used, as well as the width and height of the image, along with the image resolution in PPI and the color model and quality level you chose? It might be a lot of things that are causing this image to fail, but I can't figure out what. I have the vector file for it though, so I can scale it to any size and do what I want with it.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I got it. Check my answer. It was messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by scaling my image up by an exact factor of `1.3333333333` (I got this idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351801/wix-not-rendering-images-correctly)):

```
[ Width  ] -> 373 * 1.3333333333 = 497.3333333209
[ Height ] -> 252 * 1.3333333333 = 335.9999999916
```

This is the stupidest thing I've ever had to do. I don't know why this is the case. However, it now looks fantastic on all operating systems. I'm so displeased by this being a necessary step. PS: I also have my image at a resolution of 300 PPI.